# Is a central CAN-Bus a reliable solution for controlling robot wheels?

Tags: wheeled-robot, robot, hardware-interface, can, motor-controller

I am working as a student on a 6 wheel robot project and have problems deciding what communication protocol to use for controlling the locomotion system.

I was thinking about connecting all the robot wheel motor controllers to a local CAN-Bus and then connecting the node to a central CAN-Bus where all the main subsystems are. This would save a wiring mess, but I am worried about the reliability, since the system needs to do a lot of multitasking. I want to be sure that the robot can move, while doing other tasks.

Should I better use a SPI connection (or similar) from the OBC to the local CAN-Bus controller, or should I stick to plan? :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the bandwidth of your operations and what is the band width for your CANBUS system?